# Is there a guide to using USBccgp.sys?

Tags: windows, device-driver, inf

After days of combing through the Windows [USBccgp documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539234.aspx), I can't figure out for the life of me how to write the appropriate .INF file for my device.

This diagram shows what I'm trying to configure. This is a simplified version of what's at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540207.aspx

```
  ┌─────────────┐    ┌─────────────┐
  │ Application │    │ Application │
  ├─────────────┤    ├─────────────┤
  │ WinUSB.dll  │    │ WinUSB.dll  │
  └─────┬───────┘    └─────┬───────┘
 User   │                  │
 ───────┼──────────────────┼─────────
 Kernel │                  │
  ┌─────┴───────┐    ┌─────┴───────┐
  │ WinUSB.sys  │    │ WinUSB.sys  │
  └─────┬───────┘    └─────┬───────┘
  ┌─────┴───────┐    ┌─────┴───────┐
  │ interface 0 │    │ interface 1 │
  └─────┬───────┘    └─────┬───────┘
        └─────────┬────────┘
           ┌──────┴──────┐
           │ USBccgp.sys │
           └──────┬──────┘
            ┌─────┴─────┐
            │ My Device │
            └───────────┘
```

Basically, given the vendor and product id of my device, and the desired configuration (which unfortunately is not Configuration 1), and the interface numbers, and the endpoint numbers (which are all bulk transfer endpoints), it *ought* to be trivial to write the INF files for USBccgp.sys and WinUSB.sys to make all of this work so that I don't have to write a byte of driver code.

Are there any recipes for doing this, and/or some sample INF files? Google and Microsoft's own documentation have failed me here.